# How can I solve this Mysql issue by adding two rows into one row

Tags: mysql

when I enter this query in **SQL** I got this table

```
select agents.agent_name, agents.commission * orders.ord_amount as commission
from agents , orders
where agents.country= 'UK' and agents.agent_code = orders.agent_code;

+------------+------------+
| agent_name | commission |
+------------+------------+
| Alex       |   130.0000 |
| Benjamin   |    55.0000 |
| McDen      |    75.0000 |
| Alex       |   325.0000 |
| McDen      |   375.0000 |
+------------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

but I need to add Alex's two  commissions into one row by getting sum of these two commissions,(so do McDen's)
how to do that?
Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: ohh thanks @LaurentS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `group by` like this:

```
select agents.agent_name, sum(agents.commission * orders.ord_amount) as commission
from agents , orders
where agents.country= 'UK' and agents.agent_code = orders.agent_code
group by agents.agent_name
;
```